# Android Studio - How can I turn off leak canary for UI test automation builds (not unit tests)

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, memory-leaks, leakcanary

So I need to turn off leak canary for UI test automation builds. I followed documentation on [official website](https://square.github.io/leakcanary/recipes/) for leak canary but it was not that helpful.

I had this implementation on build.gradle(:core)

```
debugImplementation AppDependencies.leakCanary
```

And in the build.gradle(:mobile) I found these

```
productFlavors {

    flavorDimensions 'playServices'
    // I added below part from the documentation
    qa {
    }
    dev {
    }
}
```

But after these steps I am stuck. I would be very grateful if someone with experience in this could help.